# Can I print just the content of a html template in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, xhtml2pdf

I am using Django with python to create a web application, I am a beginner in this. I hope that you can help me. 
I want to print this page by clicking a button. 
Now, I am just trying to generate the pdf first. 
I want just to print the content, like that 
[image]

I tried these functions.

```
#views.py
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from MagasinProject.views import PdfMixin
from MagasinProject.utils import generate_pdf, render_to_pdf_response, pdf_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

def test_view(request):
   resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
   result = generate_pdf('demande/demande.html', file_object=resp) 
   return result
#urls.py        
from django.urls import path
from . import views 
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns=[
     path('demande',views.index, name='demande'),
     url(r'^test_view$', views.test_view),
        ]
```

This is what I got 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried to add photos but they don't work I don't know why

Comment: Kindly add your html file which you are trying to convert to pdf .

Answer (score 0):

You can print the HTML page with a print button like this ([see w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)):

```html
<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
```